# Not able to Debug Azure Timer Function in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: function, azure, debugging, timer, azure-functions

When I debug the Timer Function, I get the message (forever) and cannot continue debugging...
"The host is taking longer than expected to start"

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue although my function is a Service Bus Topic Trigger.  I was debugging it fine for a while but now it has stopped connecting to the host and I get the same message.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I resolved it by setting values for **AzureWebJobsDashboard** and **AzureWebJobsStorage** in my local.settings.json file.

I obtained these values from the Azure portal under:

Function Apps -> *FunctionAppName* -> Function app settings -> Manage application settings